# Spring MVC, jQuery with ajax - getting 415

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, http-status-code-415

I am using Jquery to send an AJAX POST request. On success I need to redirect the user to a different page, on failure I want to stay on the page with the same data.

I am having 2 issues.

1. On SUCCESS, it is not redirecting, it stays on same URL & gives a 415
2. On FAILURE, I get a 415 instead of the page getting rendered.

Here is my code:

```
 var jsonResponse = [];
 //jsonResponse is being constructed from the form data, on submit.

 var req = {
            "name" : "${name}",
            "id" : "${id}",
            "data" : jsonResponse
    };


 $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType:'application/json',
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(req),
        success: function(result) {

            url = window.location.href;
            url = url.replace("processData", "getData");
            alert(url); //prints localhost:8000/getData
            location.href = url; //stays on localhost:8000/processData
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("--- Failure ---");
            // should stay on same page with the previous data, but
            //returns a 415.
        }
    });
```

Controller for url1

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "processData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String post( Model model,
                    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, 
                    @RequestBody FormModel model) {

}
```

Controller for url2:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String get(Model model, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest)
{
}
```

I am attaching snapshot of the Error Message I get.
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: would you try removing  contentType:'application/json' from ajax paramter if it works

Comment: do you get this error as a response from ur AJAX call ? or when your SUCCESS/ERROR function is executed ?

Comment: @Patel when the success/error callback is executed, it prints the alerts() and then renders a 415 exception.

Comment: @arunbahal It doesn't work. After removing it, control does not even reach the controller.

Comment: You have not shared full URLs. It would be great if you provide full URLs as well as what data you are passing

Comment: @Patel updated the question with urls and data. My controller is able to process the data. The issue occurs when I return the control back to the jsp(ajax callback)

Comment: Have you added jackson classes in classpath?

Comment: @Tobías yes, I found the issue, It was that the form was also submitting the data & the page was getting refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the form. I had a Submit button which was also submitting the data after AJAX call ended. So I had to remove that functionality.

Initially:

```
<input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

Now:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" />
```

Better approach is to override the default Submit functionality.

```
 $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Here the answer to a question I asked : [Form Processing via AJAX - Avoiding both GET & POST Requests from getting generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32953573/form-processing-via-ajax-avoiding-both-get-post-requests-from-getting-genera)